# Show/Hide Div with size and consecutive days from checkboxes selected

Tags: jquery

The js below reveals a div based on the amount(size) of checkboxes vselected and it works fine. The checkboxes themselves are consecutive dates. What I need is to make sure that the dates selected are in consecutive order - ie 07/04, 07/05, 07/06 e.t.c. If the dates are not in consecutive order then the div does not reveal(show).

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
   if($('input:checked').size() > 4){
     $("#hideocrp").show();   
   }
   else {
     $('#hideocrp').hide()   
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to achieve your goals:

```
var start = false;
var checkstart = false;
$('#hideocrp').hide();
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
  checkstart = false;
  start = false;
  $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      var index = $(this).index("input[type=checkbox]");
      if (start == false) {
        start = index + 1;
      }
      if (index == start - 1) {
        start = start + 1;
        checkstart++;
      } else {
        checkstart = false;
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
  if (checkstart > 3) {
    $("#hideocrp").show();
  } else {
    $('#hideocrp').hide();
  }
});
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RYBK5/2/show) | [Demo source](http://jsfiddle.net/RYBK5/2/)

**Edit:**
Try using this code to do a relaxed search of a consecutive checkbox match.

```
var start = false;
var checkstart = false;
$('#hideocrp').hide();
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
  checkstart = 0;
  start = false;
  $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      var index = $(this).index("input[type=checkbox]");
      if (index == 0) {
        start = index+1;
      }
      if (index == start+1) {
        start = start + 1;
        checkstart++;
      } else {
        if (checkstart < 4) {
          checkstart = 1;
          start = index;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
  });
  if (checkstart > 3) {
    $("#hideocrp").show();
  } else {
    $('#hideocrp').hide();
  }
});
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RYBK5/6/show) | [Demo source](http://jsfiddle.net/RYBK5/6/)

**Edit2:**

To solve your second issue, just use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type=checkbox]').trigger("change");
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RYBK5/7/show) | [Source](http://jsfiddle.net/RYBK5/7/)

[To test against](http://jsfiddle.net/RYBK5/8/show)

Comment: Thanks for your help. It does work as is but I need it to reveal(show) div if 4 or more consecutive checkboxes are selected. Your solution works when one is selected...

Comment: See updated answer for code that meets your requirements.. Just forgot what checkstart was there for...

Comment: Thank you. It works great. However upon testing... If the first date is selected and then the next date not selected and then the next four consecutive dates are checked it does not reveal the div... Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Thank you so much. It even works with the php variables that I use for different events/dates(amounts). Cheers! Send me your e-mail as I have lots of odds and ends such as this that are in the budget.

Comment: extramaster Tried without results to have hidden div stay revealed upon page reload. Any suggestions? Thanks. KM

Comment: It's hard to give an answer based upon nothing.. However I have seen your other question. I don't see anything wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/ETpP4/3/

Comment: Thanks. It's based on the above question/script. It reveals when three+ are selected, then after form is submitted a thanks page is generated but if they go back a previous page to change anything the revealed div is hidden although the three+ checkboxes are checked. And yes, it is similar to the other question I posted - and that script works fine if the page is refreshed. Sorry for the confusion.